# Cross-compiling Golang in Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: go, cross-compiling, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to configure Bitbucket Pipelines to automatically compile Golang code to Linux, OSX, and Windows.  I'm using Go's cross-compile functionality for this; the pipeline is running a Linux environment, and cross-compiling to OSX and Windows by setting the values of GOOS and GOARCH.  However, I can't get the Windows build to work- it errors and tells me that it can't find a certain package.  Both the Linux and OSX builds succeed.  However, the Windows build fails, telling me it can't find /go/src/github.com/sirupsen/logrus/hooks/syslog.  Both of the previous builds used this package successfully, and running both of

```
ls /go/src/github.com/sirupsen/logrus/hooks/syslog
ls ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/sirupsen/logrus/hooks/syslog
```

the line before the build command displays two Go files in that folder.  I suspect something might be wrong with maybe the windows filesystem trying to talk to the Linux filesystem?  I've spent a few hours searching and experimenting, but nothing seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: That's because the `syslog` code, since it's accessing a Unix/Linux service, is configured not to build on Windows, as the special comment (build tag) at the top of https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/blob/master/hooks/syslog/syslog.go shows. Slightly longer version in an answer coming.

Comment: (So it's not a Pipelines issue, etc. You need to make sure the actual code, when built on Windows, only references packages that are available for Windows.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`syslog` is a platform-specific service, so [the Logrus syslog hook code](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/blob/master/hooks/syslog/syslog.go) has a special comment, called a [build tag](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints), to 
tell the Go tools not to build it on Windows (or Native Client or [Plan9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs)):

```
// +build !windows,!nacl,!plan9
```

Unless you don't want syslog integration even on Linux, you probably want to fork the application code that currently always imports `hooks/syslog` into two versions, one for platforms with syslog, one for those without. If the file importing `hooks/syslog` is currently, say, `logconfig.go`, you could create two files `logconfig_syslog.go` and `logconfig_nosyslog.go`, the `syslog` version with a constraint like the one above, and the `nosyslog` version with the opposite (`// +build windows,nacl,plan9`).

[Dave Cheney wrote a bit more about build tags and the various flavors of Go conditional compilation.](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/10/12/how-to-use-conditional-compilation-with-the-go-build-tool)